# handle error codes from SOAP request via Powershell

Tags: powershell, soap, capture, status

I have this code..

```
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest  -Headers $Headers -uri $endpoint -Method Post -Body $body  -ContentType "text/xml" -OutFile "myData.xml"
```

I tried this but it does not work..

```
$Status= $Response.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
LogWrite $Status
LogWrite $Response
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"it does not work.."_ ??

Comment: I changed code to this and it works..    

 $StatusCode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
 $Status= $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__